# Empty string when accessing dictionary value in Jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

Trying to add the value of `item['val']` to the table results in empty space
`item.num` is a list of numbers that is shown as an integer on the table, where as `item.val` is a float number that needs to be shown as is on the table

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
        items = Item.query.filter_by().all()
        # item.num is a list of items 
        # item.val is a float value 
        tmp = {"item_num":item.num , "item_val":str(item.val)}
        result[item.name] = tmp

    return render_template("information.html", info=result)
```

`information.html`

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">item num</th>
      <th scope="col">item val</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in info %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['num'] | length }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['val'] }}</td>

    </tr>
    {%endfor%}

  </tbody>
```

how do you add a value from the dictionary to the table

Comment: Why are you converting your database entries to a dict and not iterating over them directly?

Comment: @Detlef I am using two tables one called item the other has values of item the numbers list `item['num']`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a dict with a nested dict, like in this example. The name of an item represents the key value under which further data is stored. Since you don't mention your second table in your code, I can't refer to that one.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    items = Item.query.all()
    result = { item.name: {'num': item.num, 'val':str(item.val)} for item in items }
    return render_template('information.html', info=result)
```

So you can iterate over all key-value pairs with the keyword `items()` and then query the data from the nested dict.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">name</th>
    <th scope="col">item num</th>
    <th scope="col">item val</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for k,v in info.items() %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ k }}</td>
    <td>{{ v['num'] | length }}</td>
    <td>{{ v['val'] }}</td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
</tbody>
```